# jQuery before() Method and form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Is there any way to use the jQuery before method to insert a form.
For example i have the following code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("button").before('<form><input type="textfield" id="item_name" name="item_name"placeholder="item name" value=""></form>');
  });
});

</script>

<button>Add another product</button>
```

Instead of adding text in the `var text1/2/3` i would like to add a form.

Comment: It is perfectly possible, in the same way you're adding `<b>` and `<i>` elements right now. What's the problem?

Comment: doesn't seem to be working on any of my attempts. Just wanted to ensure it was possible before spending anymore time on it

Comment: I don't see a `<form>`, nor your attempt to use `.before()`

Comment: Because it does not work, so i included script i know works. The .bfore() is in a separate button

Comment: So you post a vaguely related code block instead? Please post the code you have tried in your question, so we can see what you're working with. Obviously what you tried doesn't work, otherwise you wouldn't have posted a question here.

Comment: I agree with @j08691 - you have asked a question and given unrelated code. Your original question asks about inserting a form, yet your code does not reference the <form> tag anywhere leading me to think you are asking about inserting something else somewhere else.

Comment: I understand. I was really asking if it was possible first. as i can't seem to get anywhere with it, and have used over 5 sets of code. didn't want to spend anymore time on it if it cannot be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$('body').append('<form><input type="text" /><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>');
```

Your selector (instead of `body`) -> Insert the DOM (in your case a `form`)

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8agr3acq/3/)